# Chartboost: cache once or every time

Tags: caching, ads, chartboost

In this  [doc](https://s3.amazonaws.com/chartboost/docs/ChartboostSetupGuide.pdf) it says: "Cached interstitials are deleted from memory after they are shown. If you plan to display 
another interstitial for a particular location, you should cache that location again"

**page 3 / caching**

But in every example I met there's the caching only for once, even in the chartboost [example project](https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples/tree/master/iOS/ChartboostExample)

**So the question is:** should I use `[cb cacheInterstitial:@"Pause screen"];` only once at the beginning or should I use very time I showed a cached ad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Displaying cached ads is definitely the best user experience, so I'd recommend doing it every time!

If you look down to the `- (void)didDismissInterstitial:(NSString *)location` method in the example project, you'll see that they're caching again.

This delegate method is fired every time an interstitial is clicked or closed, so adding `cacheInterstitial:location` here will immediately recache an interstitial for the location every single time!

Don't forget to add `cb.delegate = self;` after initializing the cb object to ensure that the delegate methods work properly.

Full Disclosure: I work for Chartboost.

Comment: Yeah you are right, the recaching is really there, I must have missed it somehow, thanks for your help!